# Question connected to triangular numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the pattern given below :

$$\matrix{&&&&&1&&&&&\\
&&&&2&&3&&&\\
&&&4&&5&&6&&\\
&&7&&8&&9&&10\\
&11&&12&&13&&14&&15\\
-&-&-&-&-&-&-&-&-&-&-&}$$

1. Find the last number in the $20$th row.

(possible answers: $210, 185, 228, 195$, none of these)

2. What is the sum of the numbers in the $24$th row?

(possible answers: $8801, 5335, 6924, 7208$, none of these)

I solved the first question as the last terms are of a series with general term = $\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}x$ and the answer is $210$.

But I am unable to come to the general term for the sum of numbers in
the nth row and it is difficult to find the answer without it. Please guide me on how to solve this question.

Comment: **Hint :** the sum of elements within the 24th row will be made of the whole triangle until the 24th row minus the whole triangle until the 23th row.

Comment: Oh yeahhh! Lemme try it

Comment: If I am not wrong I will have to find the last element of 23rd row as it will serve for no. of elements until the 23th row and do the same for 2th row and minus the required and reach to the answer? And did I solve the first one correctly? or there is an easy way?

Comment: Let $N_{23}$ be the last number of the 23rd row and $N_{24}$ the last number of the 24th row. These you can compute, right? (your approach sounds good, yes).  Then it's just $(N_{23} + 1)+(N_{23} + 2)+\dots + N_{24}$. Hint: how many elements in the 24th row?

Comment: @DarshitSharma  My hint may misleading as it is formulated, but I provided an answer in order to explicit the reasoning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $N_n$ be the last element of the $n^\mathrm{th}$ row. The way the triangle is constructed implies that $N_n$ is equal to the sum of all the preceding numbers, hence
$$
N_n = \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1),
$$
which is what you have found for the first question. The numbers $N_n$ are precisely named the triangle numbers. Now, the $n^\mathrm{th}$ row contains all the integers from $N_{n-1}+1$ to $N_{n-1}+n=N_n$. In consequence, the wanted sum is given by
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n (N_{n-1}+k) 
   &= nN_{n-1} + \sum_{k=1}^n k \\
   &= nN_{n-1} + N_n \\
   &= \frac{1}{2}n^2(n-1) + \frac{1}{2}n(n+1) \\
   &= \frac{1}{2}n(n^2+1)
\end{align}
$$
hence answer (C) 6,924 when $n = 24$.

Comment: [+1] A detail : A more usual term is ["triangular numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)